# Is there a constant representing the Engel Expansion of the Primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, constants

Given the set of all prime numbers $P$, is there a constant that has an Engel Expansion of $P$?

I coded a script to calculate the number, and it is about $0.705230171791801...$

Mathematically, the number can be found like this, with $k$ used as a placeholder for the number:

$$k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n{1\over p_i\#}={1\over2}+{1\over6}+{1\over30}...$$

Where $p_k\#$ is the primorial of the $k$th prime.

I google searched the result I got, but I found no results.

I guess I'm just wondering if anybody has come across this number before.

Comment: Except as an example of real number whose proof of irrationality is similar to $\sum_n \frac{1}{n!}$, I doubt this constant $\sum_n \frac{1}{\# n}$ will show very useful.

Comment: @reuns it seems to pop up in abstract physics

Comment: Not convinced :)

Answer (score 2):

Your script is wrong (an off-by-one error). My Maple computation gives:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n{1\over p_i\#} \approx 0.70523017179180096514743168$$
If you search with `inverse primorial series`you find among others this statement

> The sum of the reciprocals is given by:
>   $$S=1/2+1/6+1/30+1/210+1/2310+1/30030+1/510510+1/9699690\\+1/223092870+1/6469
> 693230+1/200560490130+1/742073813 + \dots\\ =  0,7052301717918$$
>   This value is very near to the spin of the final black hole produced by the collision of two blacks holes and calculated from the observations of gravitational waves.

in https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/nardelli2017a.pdf.

I honestly cannot judge the truth of the last sentence.

Comment: The script used `range(i)` instead of `range(1,i)`, thanks for the observation.

Comment: Related Phys.SE post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/376993/2451

Comment: @qmechanic: I share your classification of the whole paper as numerology. Thank you for the link.